# React - Dynamic Slider

Tags: reactjs, rangeslider

I am trying to use react-rangeslider dynamically. Depending on the size of an array, that many sliders should be rendered. The problem is, I am unable to get them to reference different values. Right now, the Sliders are all referencing the same value and therefore all updating the same. I would like each Slider to act independently.

The problem I have encountered when trying to solve this is since the Slider is created in the for loop, the index (i) has reached the end (The component is rendered arr.length times) and so I cannot use this as a way to index into an array of values where each index is associated to each slider.

```
//value is set as a state i.e. value: 5    

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    <Slider
     min={0}
     max={10}
     value={value}
     orientation="horizontal"
    onChange={this.handleOnChange}
  />
}

  handleChange = value => {
   this.setState({
    value: value
  })
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the id={i} in the slider and then access it in the handleOnChange function.

Some thing like this should work:

Store each slider value in an array in the state. On the slider value change event, update the state with the index passed from that slider.

```
this.state = {
    sliderValues: []
}

handleOnChange = (id, value) => {
  let sliderValues = [...this.state.sliderValues];

    let sliderValue = {
    ...sliderValues[id],
    value: value
    }

    sliderValues[id] = sliderValue;
    this.setState({sliderValues});
 }

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)   {
    <Slider
     min={0}
     max={10}
     value={this.state.sliderValues[i]}
     orientation="horizontal"
     onChange={(e) => this.handleOnChange(i, e.target.value)}/>
 }
```

Comment: H How do I get know which slider has which id? In handleOnChange how would I make Slider update independently based on id?

Comment: I have updated the answer, hope that is now clear to you.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I also get an error Cannot read property 'id' of undefined. Not sure how to read id in handlefunction. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you see "id" being included in the HTML of your slider?

Comment: No I cannot see it in elements on inspect. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, then there is another way out, i.e., passing the value in the handle function itself. See the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks! The only thing is the slider does not update with the value. The value does update but the slider doesn't

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I missed the assignment of the slider value to the array. Added sliderValues[id] = sliderValue; before the setState.

Comment: Sorry to keep bothering you but its still not working aha

Comment: Do console.log(sliderValues) just before setState inside the handle function and see whats printing there.... it should be array on numbers.

Comment: this was the output. sliderValues: ,,[object Object]

Comment: I suspected that. Change the code to this: let sliderValue = { ...sliderValues[id], value  }   It should create array of numbers and not array of objects.

Comment: SliderValues is still an object